# Soft keyboard not showing on phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, android-softkeyboard

I am using the following code to show the soft-keyboard on the webview once it loads. But it does not work. Any help will appreciated.

```
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

            mgr.showSoftInput(this.appView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

            ((InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(this.appView, 0);

            //NOTE: this code should be called after loadurl : disable the default 'save image as' and 'text selection' android dialog boxes on long clicks
            this.appView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            this.appView.setLongClickable(false);

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

At this link you will find useful information that maybe will help you solve your problem:

http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/show-soft-keyboard-automatically-when-edittext-receives-focus/

Although the author doesn't recommend it, using attribute android:windowSoftInputMode in your Manifest could eventually help you.